# Salesforce Managed package distribution

Tags: managed-package, isv, package-install

I´m creating a Salesforce managed package with all my components.
I would like to distribute it adding the URL INSTALLATION LINK on a web page of my site (not pushing the App on the AppExchange market).

I would like that users will install my package just using the link.

Is it feasible?
are there some legal problem with Salesforce?

I haven´t found references to this checking Salesforce documentation.

Thanks in advantage for any advice.